# In the Rally SDK how do you create a filter that tests the child of the config's type's child?

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

My specific goal is to create a list of all test cases for an iteration. My initial approach was to create a cardboard with type Test Case and to use a filter with the property WorkProduct.Iteration. That didn't seem to work, nor did WorkProduct.Iteration.Name. (Using the code that is otherwise identical to filter on things like WorkProduct.Description is working, so the issue seems to be what I am specifying for the filter property.)

So question #1 is: How do I get all the test cases for a given iteration (when each test case is assigned to a user story, and each user story is assigned to the iteration)? Should I be using a context statement in the config instead of a filter? Should I use some other container?

Question #2 is: In general, is it possible to use something like WorkProduct.Iteration.Name as a filter property to access values of a child element of a child element of the type you're trying to display?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In this case you'll get back this error from web services:

```
"Could not parse: Could not traverse to \"Iteration\" on type Artifact in the query segment \"WorkProduct.Iteration\""
```

This is due to the fact that in Rally's data model the WorkProduct associated with a testcase may be any artifact (not necessarily a schedulable one).

The general way to get this data would be to first query for all the stories in a given iteration and include the TestCases and any fields on TestCase in the fetch.

Unfortunately in the current preview edition of the SDK 2.0 the CardBoard component doesn't yet support supplying custom pre-queried data.  This feature should be included in the GA though.

Comment: Thanks Kyle. Once I tried some other types, I saw that I could filter on using a multi-level path. I thought I'd found something. Since a general work product seems to have Project, & a Project has Iterations, I thought this might work:

                        property: 'WorkProduct.Project.Iterations.ObjectID',
                        operator: '=',
                        value:    '7908854538'

However, I get all test cases for the project when I use that (or various variations for something after Iterations). 

Do you see any hope for a filter like this to find a specific iteration?